# Bound the dual variables of an LP

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I have a standard form problem $P = \max\{r'x:Ax\leq b, x\geq0\}$ with dual $D=\min\{b'y:A'y\geq r,y\geq 0\}$.

I want to obtain bounds on optimal dual variables $\bar y$. In other words, if $\bar y$ is optimal, how to obtain upper bounds $\bar y_i\leq something$, for some component $i$?

Hopefully the bound does not depend on $b$, but on $r$ and $A$ only.

My intuition is that $y_i$ is the gain by an extra unit of $b_i$, hence the following problem should provide a bound: $P_i = \max\{r'x:Ax\leq e_i, x\geq0\}$, with $e_i$ the canonical vector.

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: The bounds can be obtained by solving $\min\{\pm e_i'y:A'y\geq r,y\geq 0\}$.

Comment: @LinAlg Since the dual is a covering problem, $\min\{-e_i'y:A'y\geq r,y\geq 0\}$ will be unbounded in any practical scenario.

Comment: Since you want an answer independent of $b$, what do you expect when $b=\pm e_i$?

Comment: @LinAlg It's a packing problem, so with $b=e_i$ I expect to get a reasonable bound and with $b=-e_i$ the primal is infeasible.

Comment: What cost are you willing to pay for the bounds? For example, what's wrong with actually solving the dual problem?

Comment: @AlexShtof I want "theoretical" bounds. In particular, the "worst shadow price" I'm after is useful to argue worst-case bounds.

Comment: You mean something you can easily and efficiently compute?

Comment: @AlexShtof any bound I can prove. In other words, not a "numerical" result

Comment: Then I am not sure you can prove a bound, since in many cases the dual variables, as the optimal primal variables, may be unbounded (even when the problem has an optimal solution). For example, imagine in two dimensions that an entire infinite ray is optimal.